# Sending email from my provider back to my provider with data from user input secure?

Tags: email, email-attachments

My boss wants me to create the following functionality:

A user fills out a form on our website with some data. He can also upload some files, which have personal information.

After the form is submitted an email is sent to my boss with the information from the form and all files attached.

I am using Python & Flask for the backend and host it on heroku. The mail server is from our webhost (germany). So we basically send an email from us back to us.

The website with the form has SSL protection

Can this be somehow unsecure? Its an unusual approach and I have never heard of it. Is this a legit way to retrieve data? I would usually use a DB and upload the files to a storage like S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be somehow unsecure?

The website itself as HTTPS so the transport of the data from the client to your site is secured (assuming HTTPS is properly setup).

The data send from the client are now in plain on your server and anybody with the same or higher privileges than you can access these data.  If this is a shared hosting this usually means every other hosting user since the these run usually all as the same non-privileged user (i.e. `www-data` or similar, depending on the setup).

You then pack these unprotected data into a mail and deliver the mail. If you use TLS for mail delivery it is protected at least from the server to the next mail server, but you have no control over the next hops in mail delivery. But maybe even the delivery from the server to the first hop is also not protected by TLS. Anyway - without TLS the content can be sniffed when delivered in-between the mail server, with TLS it can still be sniffed on the mail servers since only the transport between mail servers is protected by TLS. To close at least this problem you can encrypt the mail itself, for example using PGP or S/MIME.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some kind of Javascript based form submit mechanism (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript for example) it would be way more state of the art to encrypt the data already inside the user's browser using a public key, send the ciphertext through whatever links across the Internet and decrypt it only in the very end.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to introduce risk since you don't control the backend. The mail system could be changed by the provider. Since you are relying on MX records you are sort of at their mercy. Depending on the data being transmitted it might run afoul of GDPR.

As you have Flask and Python already, why not send store it in a database and write new code to allow your boss to securely view it there?

Comment: Because he wants it badly this way. I have at least now some good and solid arguments to make him use the classical DB approach